# Cannot reference script-level variable in function?

Tags: javascript, function, web

My code:

```
f();

var a = {v: 10};

function f() {
    console.log(a.v);
}
```

Gives the error that `undefined` has no property `v`.

However the following code works:

```
var a = {v: 10};

var f = function() {
    console.log(a.v);
}

f();
```

Why doesn't the first version work?

Comment: You call a function, the function is entered, your var declaration is skipped. Just use your dev console to debug the script and you will see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hoisting moves function declarations and variable declarations to the top, but doesn't move assignments.

Therefore, you first code becomes

```
var a;
function f() {
  console.log(a.v);
}
f();
a = {v: 10};
```

So when `f` is called, `a` is still `undefined`.

However, the second code becomes

```
var a, f;
a = {v: 10};
f = function() {
  console.log(a.v);
};
f();
```

So when `f` is called, `a` has been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the order. When you call the function in the first version, then the json isn't defined. So it tries to get property of undefined object.

So it is necessary to call the function after declaring the object.